# MySQL connection problems when supplying password

Tags: php, mysql, bash

When I try to connect to the local MySQL database I am getting different results from these three methods:

1. It works when I connect with the following from the prompt:

   mysql -u root -p

This way prompts me for the password, and once typed I am connected.

1. It works when I connect with PHP and supply the server(localhost), username(root), and password.
2. It **does not work** when I connect with PHP to run a command like this:

   exec('mysql -P 3306 -u root -p'.$password.' databasename < '.$scriptfilename);

I also cannot get it to work from the prompt when I supply the password in the first line.

When I query the mysql.user table for the user root there are 3 entries:

root@::
root@127.0.0.1
root@localhost

There error I get when supplying the password in the same line is:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Anybody know whats going on?

Comment: You can try to echo the string for exec() and paste it into a bash shell to check if it is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your password contains special characters that the shell will interpret, you'll have problems unless you escape them. For example lots of punctuation will cause issues, such as `!`, `>`, `<`, `|` and more.

Generally though, do not put the password on the command-line if you can possibly help it!

To quote MySQL's **[5.3.2.2. End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-security-user.html)** document:

> Use a -pyour_pass or --password=your_pass option on the command line.
>
> This is convenient but insecure, because your password becomes visible to system status programs such as ps that may be invoked by other users to display command lines.

The other option is to store the password in a file that only the relevent users can read, and use the client config file:

> Store your password in an option file.

```
[client]
password=your_pass
```

Then the command-line would be:

```
mysql --defaults-file=/path/to/file_with_password
```

Comment: The password did indeed contain special characters, and once changed to safe/secure password no escape characters where needed, and it worked great. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than make your password less complex, you can also store the password in a file (somewhere safe!) and use that. That way the password won't be visible by anyone that can list running processes! I'll update the answer with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the host parameter like this:

```
exec('mysql -P 3306 -h localhost -u root -p'.$password.' databasename < '.$scriptfilename);
```

Comment: I tried this, same result. For some reason when I supply the password on the same line it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using --password= rather than -p, I have found it more reliable

Comment: Thank you for trying to help out, but it ended up being the use of special characters that caused the problem.